# jQuery UI Droppable on overflow: scroll div Issue

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kdMRV/8/

Instructions: drag the drag item at the bottom onto the red content area. The red should change to yellow on successful hover.

Move drag item back to the bottom of the page

Now, scroll the scrollbar as far to the right as it can go. And now the issue arises: if you drag the drag item over the red it turns yellow as expected, but even if you drag the item to the white space to the left of the container div (the one with the scroll bars and overflow: scroll), the red still turns to yellow!

Note, I am using chrome to test this, but I think it happens in at least FF3.6 and IE8

Can someone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery droppable and scrollable divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908010/jquery-droppable-and-scrollable-divs)

Comment: No issues with FF6. Please be more specific??